# Python: How to detect function completion and re-enable a button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I'm new to python and in my project I have completed implementing a function which has implementation to get data from a micro-controller (sampling data over UART to my PC).

Which takes several seconds, it depends on how many samples I wish to collect. This works fine with straightforward python script.

However, I wish to implement a GUI and I chose PyQt to do it. All I want to do is call the function when a button is pressed.

I will try to explain what I want to achieve in sequential steps below:

1. Click the button.
2. Button is disabled.
3. Call the function collectDataFromUART().
4. Wait for/detect the data collection to complete (Several Seconds)
5. Re-enable the button.

I have a button `clicked` handler, as shown below:

```
    self.ui.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.handlepushButton1)

    def handlepushButton1(self):
       self.ui.textEdit1.append("Started")
       collectDataFromUART()
```

What I'm not able to understand is how to detect the completion of the function collectDataFromUART() and only then re-enable the button.

Can anyone throw light on this? Examples will be really very helpful.

Help! Thank you.

Comment: Adding this as a comment rather than answer because I'm not expert with either of these libs or this use of python. But you could add a variable perhaps? Something like `running = true` at the start of the function and `running = false` at the end. Then make the ability to press the button rely on this variable. (THis is obviously not correct code but more like pseudo code to help explain) `while running == true: clickable == false    else: clickable == true`

Comment: Why not just put another line in `handlepushButton1` to re-enable the button? This line will run once `collectDataFromUART` returns.

Comment: The most Qt way of doing it would be by a signal (wraping the data collection in a class derived from QObject, define signals, emit signal upon end of data aquisition, connect in the gui to the signal and do whatever you want).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest put `collectDataFromUART()` in another thread and `emit` message when it done. Something like this:

```
mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class NamedThread(QtCore.QThread):        
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
    def run(self):
        <some code from collectDataUART>
        self.mysignal.emit()

class NamedWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        <some code>
        self.thread = NamedThread()
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.handlepushButton1)
        self.thread.mysignal.connect(lambda: self.pushButton1.setEnabled(True), QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def handlepushButton1(self):
       self.pushButton1.setDisabled(True)
       self.thread.start()
```

You also can add some information about status of execution in signal. To do so you need `pyqtSiglnal([type of data you want to send])` after that just call emit with some data `self.mysignal[type of data].emit(<data>)`

Answer (score 1):

For my opinion, sound like your should handle it by create `QThread` to receive your UART data. First, your have initiate thread for receive your UART data and close button. Next, wait for this thread. If success or fail, Create signal send back to main widget. Last, Handle signal data it and do want your want;

Little example;

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

def collectDataFromUART ():
    # Your collect data from UART
    time.sleep(1)
    data = 'UART'
    return data

class QCustomThread (QtCore.QThread):
    status = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, object)

    def __init__ (self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomThread, self).__init__(parentQWidget)

    def run (self):
        try:
            data = collectDataFromUART()
            errorCode = None
        except Exception, error:
            data = None
            errorCode = str(error)
        self.status.emit(data, errorCode)
        self.exit(0)

class QCustomMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(QCustomMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.startQPushButton = QtGui.QPushButton('START')
        self.startQPushButton.released.connect(self.requestWork)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.startQPushButton)

    def requestWork (self):
        self.startQPushButton.setEnabled(False)
        myQCustomThread = QCustomThread(self)
        myQCustomThread.status.connect(self.relpyWork)
        myQCustomThread.start()

    def relpyWork (self, data, errorCode):
        self.startQPushButton.setEnabled(True)
        if errorCode == None:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Information', data)
        else:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Critical', errorCode)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQCustomMainWindow = QCustomMainWindow()
myQCustomMainWindow.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```